# How to define a script that provides the become password in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have successfully set up a `vault_password_file` that contains a script to read the password from Bitwarden.

I want to do the same for the "become password" but don't see where and how that would be possible.

The ansible.cfg is:

```
[defaults]
inventory=./inventory.yml
vault_password_file=./ansible-vault-pass.sh

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
```

Ansible-vault-pass is the following, though the details don't matter, this works:

```
#!/bin/bash

_BW_ENTRY_ID="my-ansible-vault-pass"
_bw_session="$(bw unlock --raw)"
echo "$(bw get password ${_BW_ENTRY_ID} --session ${_bw_session} --raw)"
```

I have a similar script to look up and return the become password, but cannot find how to hook that into the config to be used instead of prompting the user.

I am aware of setting this in `group_vars/all/clear.yml`, e.g. as follows:

```
ansible_become_password: "{{ vault_enabled_ansible_become_password }}"
```

And then storing the password in the vault. Problem with that approach is that the vault is shared amongst sysadmins that can run ansible on the server fleet. But I don't want any such syadmin to be able to read the sudo password of their colleagues. Hence the approach with Bitwarden/script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with these kinds of questions is that there are several answers, and the "right" one depends on your workflow and tolerance for customization. That said, here are a few I know of:

- Using a dynamic inventory script to populate the `ansible_become_pass` var based on whatever logic you wish
- Copy a [bitwarden lookup plugin](https://github.com/c0sco/ansible-modules-bitwarden/blob/master/lookup_plugins/bitwarden.py) into [`lookup_plugins`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup.html#enabling-lookup-plugins) and then set `ansible_become_pass: '{{ lookup("bitwarden", "whatever", field="password") }}'`
- Copy the [become plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.6/lib/ansible/plugins/become/sudo.py#L76) into [`become_plugins`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/become.html#enabling-become-plugins) and modify it to [return the pass from `get_option("become_pass")`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.6/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py#L950) using a mechanism of your choice
- Using a custom `ansible-playbook-with-bitwarden` shell script that will populate [`$ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASS`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/become/sudo.html#parameter-become_pass) before launching `ansible-playbook`